# jQuery click trigger applied to arrow key not working

Tags: jquery, triggers, arrow-keys

I was trying to apply arrow navigation to an image gallery using jQuery's trigger() method.

I got an example of that from another stackoverflow user and it seemed to be fine but when I added real links to the list items they would only load when clicked and not when the arrow keys were pressed.

[In this JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DPHWZ/1/) the last two list items, "apple" and "microsoft" have the real links, they should load the pages onto the iFrame when they're activated by the arrow keys but they don't. They only properly work when clicked.

How do I make the key presses equal to the clicks?

```
var chosen = "";
$(document).keydown(function(e){ // 38-up, 40-down
    chosen = $('li.selected').index(); //grab the current selection
    if (e.keyCode == 40) { 
        if(chosen === "") {
            chosen = 0;
        } else if((chosen+1) < $('li').length) {
            chosen++; 
        }
        selectImage(chosen);
        return false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 38) { 
        if(chosen === "") {
            chosen = 0;
        } else if(chosen > 0) {
            chosen--;            
        }
        selectImage(chosen);
        return false;
    }
});

function selectImage(whichIndex) {
    $('li:eq('+whichIndex+') a').trigger("click");
}
$("#selection a").click(function() {
    $('li').removeClass('selected'); 
    $(this).parent().addClass('selected');

    $("#debug").text( $(this).attr("href") +" was just clicked");   
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.trigger()` function will only cause the handler methods that you attached with jQuery to execute. It will not cause the normal behavior of the `<a>` elements to execute. That is, it will not load the `<iframe>`.

You could use `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the `<a>` element from performing its default behavior, and add code that performs it explicitly. That way, it will execute both when it is clicked and when `.trigger()` is called.

In your case, you would need to set the `src` property of the `<iframe>`.

Try changing the event handler to this:

```
$("#selection a").click(function(e) {
    var $a = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();
    $a.parent().addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    $('iframe[name=iframeload]').prop('src', $a.attr('href'));
    $("#debug").text( $a.attr("href") +" was just clicked");   
});
```

Comment: I don't know how to apply this …does it go in the script? because I'll have to point to many different links, I'll want to specify the links in the html markup.

Comment: @Rene - Was your last comment before I updated my answer? If so, see the update.

Comment: Yes I wrote the last comment before the updated answer. Thanks! I'll look into this tonight.

Comment: Perfect! I just managed to add this and it's working just how I wanted with another javascript action being triggered with each click/key press. Thanks a lot.

Comment: [Here it is in use](http://pixelfreak.com/y/) …would it be possible to make the top thumbnail the default selection by the script? pressing arrow down selects it but since it's already selected in the html it just loads it again.  Also: would it be possible to make each arrow press scroll 100 px up/down? or otherwise keep the selected thumbnail in sight?

Comment: Both should be possible. I can't look at it now, but I will try later.

Comment: Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/john_s/WNGWJ/2/). It fixes the issue with the down arrow getting clicked the first time. Notice that there is no "src" attribute on the iframe to begin with. It also uses `.scrollIntoView()` to do the scrolling. It's simple, but I personally would rather it not scroll until it has to. Instead, it scrolls the first time the arrow is pressed. (At least it does on FireFox.)

Comment: This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/john_s/WNGWJ/3/) scrolls the way I think it should. I'm looking forward to seeing this work on your site.

Comment: This is amazing. Thanks! I am about to implement it and I'll show you later.

Comment: Hi John… see the updated page [here](http://www.pixelfreak.com/z/). The new stuff works like it should but it somehow conflicts with two other scripts: 1. the one that moves the yellow highlight (#selection) to the current thumbnail (this uses #s19, #s18, #s17, etc. to position it) though this works fine when clicking. And 2. the one that fades in each iframe page to make the loading smoother and avoid any "white flash" (this one uses .s2ifrm and #llstrtn) …I'm embarrassed to ask for even more help but the desired result feels so close!

Comment: Try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/john_s/WNGWJ/4/). I think there might be a better way to position the highlight instead of needing the s01-s19 classes, but I left it working that way.

Comment: Yes, I think the s01-s19 solution is a little silly, having to have so many IDs but I couldn't find or figure out something cleaner, if what you think is easy to apply I'd be happy to see it. I'm about to add this. Thanks again!

Comment: In my last jsfiddle, I included a comment that suggested moving the s01-s19 classes from the `<a>` elements to the `<li>` elements. I should have said "ids", not "classes".

Comment: Well, I made an attempt to move the highlight without using the s01-s19 classes, but I came up a little short. See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/john_s/WNGWJ/5/). If you scroll down, you will see that space is reserved for the highlight, which doesn't look too good. That's the limit of my CSS and positioning knowledge.

Comment: Great! the space for the highlight can be removed with margin-bottom: -95px which is its own height. So now there seems to be just one last issue, the iframe fade-ins start from white instead of the background image and loading gif, do you know why?

Comment: Are you seeing that issue on your page, or on the jsfiddle? On the jsfiddle, I neglected to convert all of the URLs in the CSS to absolute URLs. I have fixed that now, and added the `margin-botton: -95px`. See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/john_s/WNGWJ/6/). Please note that I moved the `<img>` elements for the highlight and the copyright so they are just after the `<ul>` element. Only `<li>` elements should be inside a `<ul>` element.

Comment: (I realize that the ldgf div was out of the last sample but even when I replaced it I couldn't see it, also not even removing the iframe did it show up)

Comment: I must have removed the ldgf div. I put it back in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/john_s/WNGWJ/7/). It probably didn't work when you added it back because the URL in the CSS wasn't absolute.

Comment: :) this should do it, sorry I didn't do a good look through the code. I will get the stuff into my files later today and I guess it should all go well. I'll write later. Thanks.

Comment: [Done!](http://pixelfreak.com/z/) thanks! I wouldn't have figured this stuff out and the page is working better than I hoped. Could I gift you an app or something? :) infinity blade II?

Comment: @Rene. You're welcome. It's nice seeing the result on your live page. Thanks for the offer, but there's no need. BTW, you could remove the following line of code, it was just there for debugging on the jsfiddle: `$('#output').text('Showing index: ' + index);`.

Comment: Right! I just did that. Thanks again, really!